# Why the JVM always starts with a FULL GC?

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, jvm

I am performing tuning benchmarks on a web application that is running on JBoss AS5.

I am creating different scenarios using JMeter, starting from low load till stress load.

What I have noticed is that the GC log starts always with a full GC.

Can someone explain to me this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

FWIW, here is a snippet from a GC log:

```
17.560: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 44456K->0K(458752K)] [ParOldGen: 0K->4385K(1572864K)]      44456K->4385K(2031616K) [PSPermGen: 11565K->11555K(262144K)], 0.9226691 secs]
72.478: [GC [PSYoungGen: 393216K->30720K(458752K)] 397601K->35105K(2031616K), 0.1787110    secs]
112.137: [GC [PSYoungGen: 423936K->38912K(458752K)] 428321K->43297K(2031616K), 0.2197971 secs]
188.297: [GC [PSYoungGen: 432128K->54272K(458752K)] 436513K->58657K(2031616K), 0.3034273 secs]
309.100: [GC [PSYoungGen: 447488K->60416K(458752K)] 451873K->64801K(2031616K), 0.3111470 secs]
430.354: [GC [PSYoungGen: 453632K->65536K(454848K)] 458017K->72129K(2027712K), 0.3374716 secs]
546.078: [GC [PSYoungGen: 454848K->65536K(415104K)] 461441K->78881K(1987968K), 0.3746511 secs]
652.116: [GC [PSYoungGen: 415104K->40960K(436928K)] 428449K->88641K(2009792K), 0.3895185 secs]
765.134: [GC [PSYoungGen: 390528K->28672K(437632K)] 438209K->94882K(2010496K), 0.2703870 secs]
870.726: [GC [PSYoungGen: 380800K->23552K(375680K)] 447010K->102114K(1948544K), 0.1948568 secs]
976.144: [GC [PSYoungGen: 375680K->18432K(436096K)] 454242K->110306K(2008960K), 0.1734677 secs]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Peter Johnson from the Jboss Community. I've been able to know the answer of this question.

I am writing it here to share it with you.

> *The call to System.gc() is coded into the app server (or into one of the libraries it uses - I know the the RMI libraries like to make GC calls), I suspect as it transitions from bootstrap to the app server itself. I think it might also perform another GC or two after deployment or other major initialization activity. I think the idea behind this was to have the heap as clean of junk as possible before handling user requests. Of course, that made sense years ago when when servers didn't have that much memory and heaps were smaller. I have seen this behavior in JBoss AS release from 4.0.x up through 5.x (haven't monitored GC behavior on 6).*

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't always start with a GC, you can have a program which never GCs.

However when the JVM starts it uses a minimal amount of memory by default.

The application is building data structures and high percentage of objects will be retained.  This is not normal behaviour and the survivor space can be exhausted. The JVM is tuned to assume most objects which are newly created will be discarded. When the survivor space is exhausted a Full GC is triggered.

Since you know how much memory your application will grow to you can use an option like

```
-ms512m -mx1g
```

The full GC will go away and you will collect less often.

Comment: +Peter Thanks for your answer. these options are set to the following -Xms2g -Xmx2g

Comment: In that case I would also try setting new size `-XX:NewSize=1g` Typically I start with new size of 8 GB for a new application and reduce it from there. ;)

Comment: +Peter Thanks again. However how can you set the size of the young generation to be greater than the heap 8GB?

Comment: even after setting new size to     -XX:NewSize=1g. The problem still persist.

Comment: I use `-XX:NewSize=8g -mx12g` or the like. I what could be the problem is now. Reading the whole first line carefully, I can see the initial perm gen filled up. `PSPermGen: 11565K->11555K` This never happens in the applications as I use JSE which loads far less code.  I am not sure how to set the initial perm gen size, but you can increase the maximum which might increase the minimum.

Comment: I've found that the FullGC happens before the deployment of the application! It happens when I start the JBoss server? Any help on this??

Comment: Another point is the perm gen isn't filled up its size is 262144K and only 11565K are occupied.

Comment: its maximum size might be 256 MB, but its initial size could be 11.5 MB and after a full gc, it is grown. Are you setting the minimum size?

Comment: Yes, they are both set to 256m.